# How many matchings does a cycle on n vertices have?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

how many matchings does a cycle on n vertices have?

this is graph theory.

If n = 3, matching would be 3? and

If n = 4, matching should be 4 and

If n = 5, matching would be 10?

It seems there is no pattern

Comment: How do you get $4$ matchings for a cycle on $4$ vertices? I get $2$ matchings of size $2$, and $4$ matchings of size $1$, and . . . does the empty matching count? I get $7$ matchings, or $6$ nonempty matchings, or $2$ maximum matchings, or $2$ maximal matchings. How do you get $4$?

Comment: My guess is that they want you to count all matchings of any size, including the empty matching. In that case there seems to be a nice pattern. I get $4$ matchings for $n=3$, $7$ matchings for $n=4$, $11$ matchings for $n=5$, ...